# Active Class in Navbar - Whats wrong with my php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, navbar

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my head around some php code.
To explain:

I have a navbar made from bootstrap.
I want this nav bar to change it's active class depending on the page.
I have a subnav within the navbar with an li class of 'dropdown'.
When this page is active this li class wants to change to 'dropdown active'
When other pages are active, they just want a simple class of 'active'.

My code is as follows:
PHP:

```
    $pageLoc = 'where';
$nav_items = array('index'=>'Home', 'where'=>'Where?', 'appeals'=>'Current Appeals', 'news'=>'Latest News', 'events'=>'Events', 'dontate'=>'Dontate', );
$nav_sub = array('africa'=>'Africa', 'bangladesh'=>'Bangladesh', 'gaza'=>'Palestine/Gaza', 'kashmir'=>'Kashmir', 'pakistan'=>'Pakistan', 'uk'=>'United Kingdom' );

    foreach ($nav_items as $nav_href=>$nav_title) {
   if ($pageLoc == $nav_href) && ($pageLoc == 'where') {
         echo '<li class="dropdown active">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   }
   elseif ($pageHref == $nav_href) && ($pageLoc == 'no') {
         echo '<li class="dropdown">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   }
   elseif ($pageHref == $nav_href) {
         echo '<li class="active">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   } 
   else {
       echo '<li>' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   }
}
```

Navbar:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li class="pull-right">
                    <a class="btn-danger" href="donate"><i class="icon-medkit"> DONATE!</i></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav pull-right">
                  <li class="">
                    <a href="../">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="../where/" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Where?
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="nav-header">Where we operate</li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="../where/africa">Africa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../where/bangladesh">Bangladesh</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../where/palestine-gaza">Palestine/Gaza</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../where/kashmir">Kashmir</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../where/pakistan">Pakistan</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="">
                    <a href="../appeals">Current Appeals</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="">
                    <a href="../news">Latest News</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="">
                    <a href="../events">Events</a>
                  </li>
            </ul>
```

I am aware that this php is generating a syntax error. I am no pro unfortunately! :( This is

```
what I originally had:
foreach ($nav_items as $nav_href=>$nav_title) {
   if ($pageHref == $nav_href) {
         echo '<li class="active">' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   } 
   else {
       echo '<li>' . $nav_title . '</li>';
   }
}
```

Comment: I would start with opening the tags outside of the `if` sections and add the correct classes as your conditions are met. That would simplify things and make it easier to spot the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

```
if ($pageLoc == $nav_href) && ($pageLoc == 'where')
```

It should say:

```
if ($pageLoc == $nav_href && $pageLoc == 'where')
```

On a more general note, the absence of detailed debugging information is a pain, but there are workarounds. For example, if you delete half of the code and try to run it again*, does it still give a syntax error? If so, delete a bit more and see what happens; if not, undelete some and see if it works. Keep trying this and narrowing it down until you find where the error is.

*(obviously, don't delete in such a way that you create syntax errors; for example, if you delete the end of an `if` clause including the `}`, you'll get non-matching brackets.)